# Printing variable in Python 3 (basic)

Tags: python, variables, printing

Literally on my first day of coding (using a Python crash course book), and already running into issues. I want to assign a variable a value, and print this variable. However, I keep getting a syntax error message.

This has worked on my Terminal in OSX, but when I try to run it in Sublime Text, I get a syntax error.

```
message = ("Hello world!")
print(message)

message = ("Hello world!")
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

This is my only code in the file; this is the only the second thing I have written.

My Python3 build settings:

```
    "cmd": ["/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3", "-u", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "quiet": true
```

Thank you!

Comment: please paste the exact code (full code please) and error message surrounded by three backticks on each side so we can see the code properly (see help)

Comment: The fact it works in the terminal, I assume by running python3, but not in Sublime Text, points to an issue with Sublime Text not an issue with your code or python

Comment: is the line in the error part of something larger? Sometime you get an error on a line when the error is actually in the line before, like a missing parenthesis, etc.

Comment: Do you have any code before this?

Comment: Thank you for the help; this is my only code in the file. I think it is most likely an issue with Sublime. Any recommendations on where to look to fix this (sorry for the broad question)?

Comment: What is your Sublime setting for build system and are your running it in sublime with tools/build (ctrl + B)?

Comment: @DaveStSomeWhere I am running it with Build (Ctrl+B). My build system settings for Python 3 are attached below

Comment: @DaveStSomeWhere I actually added it to the orginal post

Comment: My sublime running 2.7 on Linux does not gen an error (also not a prob in pycharm using 3.7).
What do you get just checking the python version? 
`import sys`
`print(sys.version_info)`

Comment: @DaveStSomeWhere when I run this on the Terminal, I have no problems. However, when I run it in Sublime, I get another error message:

Comment: @DaveStSomeWhere ```import sys SyntaxError: invalid syntax``` (^ pointing to the "t" in import)

Comment: Sounds like you are not executing python since you're always getting an error on the first statement. You might have better luck with a new question about running python3 from Sublime on OSX (tagging Sublime and OSX) after verifying the Submile docs and your paths.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this and tell me if works, please.

```
message = 'Hello World!'
print(message)
```

Comment: I tried that, still getting the same error message. Likely a problem with Sublime text as someone mentioned in the comments. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it's not working is that it is expecting a tuple. You can try this.

```
message = ("Hello world!",)
print(message)
```

Comment: I gave it a try, no luck though. Probably a large issue with Sublime. Thank you though.

Comment: have you tried running from python interactive console?